# Why is <%# Eval(...) %> not rendering? Actually shows "<%# Eval(...) %>" in the client

Tags: asp.net, eval

I have the following control in ASP.Net

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="Run" CssClass="button" OnClientClick='Download( <%# Eval("ID") %> )' />
```

When I run the page, the following details are being outputted to the browser.

```
<input type="submit" name="gvMaster$ctl02$btnDownload" value="Run" onclick="DownloadReport( &lt;%# Eval(&quot;ID&quot;) %> );" id="gvMaster_btnDownload_0" class="button" />
```

Why isn't the `<%# Eval("ID") %>` actually evaluating?  To be clear, originally I had a small JS snippet within this statement.  I had to make a minor modification, so I moved it to a JS method.  After moving the code and leaving just the ID as a parameter, this result started showing up where, before, it was actually evaluating to the value in the associated record.

What could be going on?  I've not seen this before.

Comment: Been a while since I've worked on WebForms, so I'm not 100% positive, but I don't think you can set properties on server side controls using data-binding like that. You should use the `OnItemDataBound` event for the parent repeater/datagrid/etc and set it in the code behind. The exception might be something like: `OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ID", "Download({0})") %>'`, where the entire value is evaluated and sent to the attribute all at once.

Comment: I'll give this a try, but the odd thing is that the eval was working until I changed the contents of the `onclientclick` results, and stripped out the JS.  Also, I did a test and moved the `<%# Eval('ID')%>` statement outside of the control attribute, and just outputted it before the element.  It worked!?!?  Bizarre

Comment: @Sam That fixed it!  Thank you!   Feel free to post an answer for the accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposting comment as answer:

I don't think you can set properties on server side controls using data-binding like that (mixing static text and dynamic Eval values). You should use the `OnItemDataBound` event for the parent repeater/datagrid/etc and set it in the code behind, or use `OnClientClick='<%# Eval("ID", "Download({0})") %>'`, where the entire value is evaluated and sent to the attribute all at once.

Answer (score 0):

try `OnClientClick='<%# "Download(" +Eval("ID") + " );" %>'` i suspect you need the server code to evaluate the whole expression in javascript so when rendered by the browser it will correctly trigger the function.